# How to write a string of "Octal UTF-8 bytes" to a file in readable format in py 3.10? (n\303\244chsten should be appeared as nächsten)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I have a string object which has Octal UTF-8 bytes characters and I need to write them into a file in readable format. How to do that one in python 3.10?

Lets say I have group of German characters which are received in Octal UTF-8. What should I do here? I tried different encodings and decodings nothing is working out. Could some one please help me. I am new python learner and struggling to fix this out. Thanks in advance.

In simple words:

s = "n\303\244chsten"

What action I need to do to write it into a file as "nächsten"
with open(myfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
fp.write(s)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teqgd.png)

Comment: Be very specific about what you receive.  `print(ascii(s))` and tell us the content.  Do you mean you literally receive n,\,3,0,3,\,2,4,4,c,h,s,t,e,n characters separately?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]: clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  As currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using `latin1` instead of `utf-8` works fine for me:

```
s = "n\303\244chsten"
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='latin1') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: Hello PApostol, thanks for the solution you mentioned here. I tried this one which is working on individual file but i really wonder that is not working on my solution. I am type casting a variable to a string and then writing it into a file.

Comment: @PrasanthiJayam again, edit your question and provide more detail. There is no “type casting” in your question. Show what you are doing and what doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

'latin-1' or 'iso-8859-1' encondings will work